# spark_thrift_cmd_opts + how to find the right value from HW cluster info

Tags: apache-spark

in my ambari cluster the parameter:

```
spark_thrift_cmd_opts set to --driver-memory 10g --executor-cores 7
```

we have 3 masters machines and 28 data node machines ( workers machines )

each datanode have 36G memory

each datanode have 32 core

my current conf:

```
spark_thrift_cmd_opts to --driver-memory 10g --executor-cores 7
```

so according to the HW inputs , how to find the right value of **spark_thrift_cmd_opts** ??

and what is the formula to calculate this

Comment: Please stop tagging `ambari` when the question has nothing to do with it. It's just a Hadoop cluster, not an Ambari cluster

Comment: There is no magic value here... Especially since it depends on all the other workload of the cluster. You could starve all other processes, and give the highest possible memory, but then you're risking parallelism for having huge executors